# select query with where clause and group by in ms access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm having table which contains columns Id and Pcode. where ID column is foreign key. I'm trying to get the ID, which Pcode does not contains the value 'FT' with group by 'ID'.

Sample Data:

[image]

Desired Result:

ID

3

the desired result is 3. the ID column 3 does not have the Pcode FT. Can anyone help me to write a query to get the desired result. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use aggregation:

```
SELECT ID
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING SUM(IIF(PCODE = 'FA', 1, 0)) = 0
```

Comment: the output result which i need is ID = 3. the ID rows does not contains the "FT" value in the Pcode columns.

Comment: If you change the IIF statement to use 'FT' instead of 'FA', will this work?

Comment: @PRABA I updated my answer.  Sorry, I forgot that Access doesn't support `CASE`, it uses `IIF` instead.

Comment: thank you @TimBiegeleisen the updated answer works for me.